# How to get rid of Misc category?

Tags: datasource, propertygrid

[image]

Look at the image attached, I am using Visual Studio and wondering how to remove/hide the "Misc" category as it doesn't hold any value and just looks horrendous for end users. There's no code I have written so I am assuming it's a default function of Visual Studio.

[image]

I have tried going into the Data Source options I have attached and tried to delete "DeveloperString, LongString, ShortString, ID, Name and NormalString." but I cannot find any reference to deletion.

Edit:

The class I'm using doesn't have "DeveloperString, LongString, ShortString, ID, Name and NormalString." therefore, how can something be undefined when it doesn't exist to be defined?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your time and patience but I have no idea what is going on.:)

Comment: "Misc" is used by the property grid when a property has no category attribute defined: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute Add a `[Category("blahblah")]` to a property and it will be in the "blablah" category visually